# Would it have any bad influence to add @objc to a Swift method or variable?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I got some Objective-C files imported in Swift project, and tried to access some Swift classes.
According to [Apple's Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID136), I added the @objc to the method I wanted it to be exposed to Objective-C files.
But the question is, does this "@objc" have any side effect to my Swift project?
The following code is a singleton local data manager.

```
@objc class LocalDataManager {

    @objc public static let shared = LocalDataManager()
    private init() {}


    @objc var nickName: String {
        get { return loadData("nickName") } // loadData is a convenience access method to UserDefaults
        set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "nickName") }
    }
}
```

Comment: If want to expose to OC, you have no other choice. Otherwise, don't add @objc, it's bad for performance.

Comment: I agree with @Lumiialxk and the answer. It's about how the OS works. Having said that - and I don't believe this will actually have any affect on performance or size - I'm unsure you need to add `@objc` in your example to everything. Just the class should work. I'll delete this comment if wrong.

Comment: For an explanation as to *why* it slows performance, see https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2016/12/swift-method-dispatch/

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for the share. That's great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@objc` keyword does severely affect performance. The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html) states:

> applying the `@objc` attribute can increase the compiled size of an app and adversely affect performance.

Therefore, only use `@objc` if you really need too.

Comment: the doc has moved to swift org https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html#ID593